# Я совсем новичок в UMICMS но не могу найти толковых гайдов (UMICMS, tpl шаблонизатор)

Tags: umi

Я совсем новичок в UMICMS но не могу найти толковых гайдов (UMICMS, tpl шаблонизатор) те кто знаком с umicms поделитесь пожалуйста своим опытом, и тем как вы изучали umicms, с чего стоит начать изучение (разработки в целом)